# MATLAB does not show the correct calculation

Tags: matlab, variables, image-processing

I'm trying to do a simple algorithm on an image but i figured out there is a problem, here is a piece of my code:

```
I = imread('C:/test.bmp' ,'bmp');
z = I(1, 1, 1);
c = I(1, 1, 2);
b = I(1, 1, 3);
v = z+c+b
```

this piece of code should print the sum of `R,G and B` values of the first pixel. when In print each `R,G and B` individually, there are `123, 43, 140`. but the value of v(sum) is always equal to `255`! I tried it with different pics, but I get the same result!
I have no idea why is this happening, happy to get help.

Comment: Convert to double and then do additions. With the native `uint8` being read from the image, it always clips the values at 255.

Comment: @Divakar u mean with x = double(y) command?

Comment: Add this right after `imread` - `I = double(I);`

Comment: @Divakar tanx man! but I thought default data types in MATLAB are double. can u explain why is this happening?!

Comment: @Divakar: The default data type is double, but adding multiple uint8 is still a uint8. Your BMP is probably 24 bit, which is uint8 per channel.

Comment: Default call of `imread` reads the data from images as `uint8` and not `double`, thats why.

Comment: @Divakar tanx for the help and +1 for explanation ;)

Comment: @Divakar -- add your comments as an answer and I'll upvote!

Comment: @FredrikPihl nice! me too!

Comment: @Branky: I would use `im2double` instead of `double`. This scales any image values in the 0...1 range. Otherwise pictures with 16 bits per channel can cause problems.

Comment: @Daniel Sometimes they are in the [0 1] range right? I guess with `BMP`, one needs to take that extra care, so maybe `im2double` is the go to answer?

Comment: @Branky, I would too use `im2double` too as Daniel said. It's what I usually use anyway

Comment: @Daniel Why not post an answer on this? I will upvote it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the colour depth and file format, imread outputs different data types. In this case it was a uint8 with a maximum of 255. The sum of unit8 variables is also a uint8.

The easiest way to deal with it is using `im2double` while loading the images. Every colour channel is scaled to a double value in the [0,1] interval.

```
I = im2double(imread('C:/test.bmp' ,'bmp'));
```